# Real-time updates only for app's users?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, real-time

I've been reading the real-time updates documentation for a while and I can't seem to find an answer. Can I use this feature only for the app's users? Can't I define a list of IDs that I want to receive the public feed from(even though not app's users)?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/):

> **Objects**
>
> You can currently subscribe to updates for these types of objects:
>
> **user** – Get notifications about particular fields and connections
>   corresponding to user nodes in the Graph API.
>
> **permissions** – Get
>   notifications when your users change the permissions they afford your
>   applications. The fields are like those in the corresponding FQL
>   table.
>
> **page** - Get notifications when pages that have installed your
>   application change their public properties. Note that the page topic
>   is only used for subscribing to changes to public attributes of the
>   page (like name, category, picture etc). This is the same information
>   that is returned by the graph api call
>   https://graph.facebook.com/. You can subscribe to the page's
>   feed in the same way you subscribe to a user's feed - the subscription
>   topic should be 'user' and the subscription field should be 'feed'

These objects are related to YOUR application, so it would be updates from users of your applications, permissions related to your application, etc..